# Is it possible to customize UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone

When using UIImagePickerController to browse a folder, I hope to customize UIImagePickerController as below

in thumbnails mode, place a customized subview (includes a Label and a button) under each thumbnail.

Is it possible?

If not, is there any other third party's free or comercial framework can do this?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. The UIImagePickerController is a black box user interface provided by the SDK. It should not be subclassed or modified. Doing so may cause your app to be rejected during review.

You might be able to accomplish this with [Three20's TTThumbsViewController](http://api.Three20.info/interface_t_t_thumbs_view_controller.html) which you should be able to modify without risking Apple's wrath.